# Prove that $p(n)$ is the number of ways of partition of $n$

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

For a positive integer $n$, define $p(n)$ to be the number of sets of positive integers $\{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k \}$ such that $x_1 > x_2 > \dots > x_k > 0$ and $n = x_1 + x_3 + x_5 + \dots$ (sum of all odd indices element of the set). For example, $p(6) = 11$ since we could have
$$ \{ 6 \}, \{ 6, 5 \}, \{ 6, 4 \}, \{ 6, 3 \}, \{ 6, 2 \}, \{ 6, 1 \}, \{ 5, 4, 1\}, \{ 5, 3, 1 \}, \{ 5, 2, 1 \}, \{ 4, 3, 2 \}, \{ 4, 3, 2, 1\} $$
Prove that $p(n)$ is the number of partition of integer $n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

---

This is from a selection test that already ended. I think it can be done by bijection (maybe generating function), but I have no idea how to continue.

Comment: You are given that $p(n)$ is the number of ways to write $x$ in a particular way. What is your definition of a partition, and what is really your definition of $p(n)$? The description and your example do not match. ($6+5$ is not equal to $6$, for example, so cannot be a partition.)

Comment: @LetGBeTheGraph I think the definition of partition is *very well-known* in combinatorics/number theory. Take this as a small reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) . For the second part, you didn't read the question correctly: sum of *odd index*. Feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we are given an admissible set $\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$. If $k$ is odd, add $0$ to the set so its cardinality is even. Then interpret this set as a strictly decreasing sequence $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots,a_{i+1},b_{i+1})$. There is a unique Young diagram associated to the sequence, constructible as follows:

- Make an L of $a_{i+1}$ squares whose legs point down and right (like $\Gamma$), of which $b_{i+1}$ squares are right of the L's corner (white squares below).
- For $j$ from $i$ to $1$, counting down:

  - Add $a_{j+1}+1$ *compulsory* squares to the top and left edges of the diagram (blue squares below). The diagram is now not in Young form because of a notch in the top-left, but this is only temporary.
  - Add an L of $a_j-(a_{j+1}+1)$ squares (white below): one square to fill the aforementioned notch, $b_j-(a_{j+1}+1)$ squares to the right of the newly added compulsory squares on top, the remaining squares below the newly added compulsory squares on the left. Young form is now restored.

[image]

In each loop iteration we add $a_j$ squares, so the total number of squares in the finished Young diagram is $\sum_{j=1}^{i+1}=n$. It is also easy to see that different sets for which the sum of odd-indexed terms is the same $n$ lead to distinct Young diagrams of $n$ cells. This establishes a bijection between admissible sets whose odd-indexed terms sum to $n$ and Young diagrams of $n$ cells, which themselves are in bijection with partitions of $n$. Thus $p(n)$ as defined in the question is identical to the unrestricted partition function (usually denoted $p(n)$ anyway).